# Where is the error in this query

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have looked this over and over and was going to see if I could get an extra set of eyes on it. I am trying to run a create table query, but I cannot seem to get it to work. The error I am getting is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`1`, `id_shop` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT `1`, `id_lang` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAUL' at line 4
```

here the the query I am trying to run

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PREFIX_quote` (
`id_quote` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`reference` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_shop_group` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT `1`,
`id_shop` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT `1`,
`id_lang` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT `1`,
`id_customer` int(10) NOT NULL,
`total_discounts` decimal(17,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0.00`,
`total_products` decimal(17,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0.00`,
`total_product_wt` decimal(17,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0.00`,
`total_shipping` decimal(17,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0.00`,
`quote_number` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0`,
`quote_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`valid` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT `1`,
`id_employee` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
`date_upd` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_quote`),
KEY `id_customer` (`id_customer`),
KEY `id_employee` (`id_employee`));
```

Comment: I believe this to be on-topic because there is a specific error message and code example.  It is not a general "debug my code for me" question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the backticks around integers. See [the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cb9f).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PREFIX_quote` (
`id_quote` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`reference` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_shop_group` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`id_shop` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`id_lang` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`id_customer` int(10) NOT NULL,
`total_discounts` decimal(17,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
`total_products` decimal(17,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
`total_product_wt` decimal(17,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
`total_shipping` decimal(17,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
`quote_number` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`quote_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`valid` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`id_employee` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
`date_upd` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_quote`),
KEY `id_customer` (`id_customer`),
KEY `id_employee` (`id_employee`));
```

Answer (score 4):

Backticks (`) are used to quote [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) in MySQL, so that reserved words or special characters can appear in them. They are often used to enclose column names, which you're doing, even though it's often unnecessary, but not *values*: remove the backticks from your default values:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PREFIX_quote` (
`id_quote` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`reference` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_shop_group` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your value is in backticks: `` `1` ``, this is incorrect.  This be in quotes, or since it's a number, unquoted.

```
`id_shop_group` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
```

Make sure to do this for all your fields.